# How to convert docx data in tablure form with heading and subheading using python

Tags: python, docx

I have data in a docx file that looks like this and my task is to convert it into tabular form with headings and subheadings using Python. please help me to find out the solution

```
I. Introduction
   A. Definition of irritation
   B. Importance of managing and overcoming irritation
   C. Thesis statement

II. Understanding Irritation
   A. Causes of irritation (e.g., external triggers, personal factors)
  
III. Strategies for Overcoming Irritation
   A. Self-awareness and mindfulness
      1. Recognizing triggers and patterns
      
   B. Cognitive approaches
      1. Identifying and challenging irrational thoughts
     

   C. Emotional regulation
      1. Developing emotional intelligence
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.